# how to get the data-id of the li on span class click

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I have data showing using ul li as below.

```
<ul class="quotes">
    <% for(var i=0; i<quotes.length; i++) {%>
        <li class="quote" data-id= "<%= quotes[i]._id %>">
            <span><%= quotes[i].name %></span> - 
            <span><b><%= quotes[i].price %></b></span>
            <span class="remove">X</span>
        </li>
    <% } %>
</ul>
```

When I click on span with class remove i want to get the data-id of that li.

I have tried,

```
$('.remove').on('click',  function(e){
    $(this).attr('data-id');
});
```

and also tried `$(this).closest(li).`. But I am not getting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either `$(this).parent().attr('data-id')` or `$(this).closest('li').attr('data-id')` or `$(this).parents('li').attr('data-id');`

> [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) selects the first element that matches the selector, up
>   from the DOM tree.
>
> [`parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) selects one element up the DOM tree.
>
> [`parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) method is similar to [`parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) but selects all the
>   matching elements up the DOM tree.

```js
$('.remove').on('click',  function(e){
    console.log($(this).parent().attr('data-id'));
    console.log($(this).closest('li').attr('data-id'));
    console.log($(this).parents('li').attr('data-id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="quotes">
        <li class="quote" data-id="1">
            <span>name</span> - 
            <span><b>123</b></span>
            <span class="remove">X</span>
        </li>
        <li class="quote" data-id="2">
            <span>name</span> - 
            <span><b>123</b></span>
            <span class="remove">X</span>
        </li>
        <li class="quote" data-id="3">
            <span>name</span> - 
            <span><b>123</b></span>
            <span class="remove">X</span>
        </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could search the parents and get the `data-id` of it:

```
$('.remove').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parents('li').attr('data-id');
});
```

Or, simply get the immediate parent, and use the `data` method to get the value:

```
$('.remove').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().data('id');
});
```